# Running Tensorboard From Bash Shell (called from xcode using swift cocoa)

Tags: swift, xcode, bash, tensorflow, tensorboard

I have followed along this tutorial: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0 Everything runs fine when I enter it in to the terminal. I put the code into a bash shell, and am calling it as a process from xcode in a cocoa app using swift. However when it gets to calling tensorboard: `tensorboard --logdir tf_files/training_summaries &`

I am getting the error

> line 23: tensorboard: command not found

I am also recieving similar errors in regards to tensorflow, such as

> import tensorflow as tf
>   ImportError: No module named tensorflow

What am I missing here?

Comment: try this command `which tensorboard`
it returned nothing, execute this `python -m tensorflow.tensorboard --logdir=path/to/log-directory` and retry `which tensorboard`

Comment: Thank you, I came up with an implemented a less than ideal solution. I will go back and try out your advice this weekend.